# Aggregate query in same select statement

Tags: sql-server, aggregates

I have a select statement which is returning me 5 columns (and it is taking 1-2 minutes)
one column in this is color (i.e. only three colors Red, Blue and Yellow). Now I want to show the count of the number of rows having Red, Number of rows having Blue and No. of rows having yellow in the same select statement.

Select statement is this

[image]

and I want output like this

[image]

Any help ?

Comment: 1-2 minutes? How many tables and rows is it operating on?  If you add the SQL statement to your post, that will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this (For SQL Server 2005+):

```
SELECT  *, SUM(CASE WHEN Color = 'RED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER() [RED],
        SUM(CASE WHEN Color = 'BLUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER() [BLUE],
        SUM(CASE WHEN Color = 'Yellow' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER() [Yellow]
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: You either change `SUM()` to `COUNT()` or chnage the case to: `... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: This has TERRIBLE performance. This will execute 4 times as slowly.

Comment: @ypercube I added the `ELSE`. @usr I was more focused in the **single select** part of the question

Comment: @lamak Thanks for your answer. :-) I really appreciate it. you just saved my day !

Comment: @ypercube +1 for the suggestion. I have modified my query as per your suggection.

Comment: I have took my select query in CTE based on condition and than I have implemented your query, I didn't notice any performance loss, yet

Answer (score 1):

Using CTEs (Common Table Expressions):

```
; 
WITH cte AS
( SELECT ...
  ... your query here
) 
WITH grp AS
( SELECT 
        color
      , COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM
        cte
  GROUP BY
        color
) 
SELECT 
      cte.*
    , (SELECT cnt FROM grp WHERE color = 'Red')    AS Red
    , (SELECT cnt FROM grp WHERE color = 'Blue')   AS Blue
    , (SELECT cnt FROM grp WHERE color = 'Yellow') AS Yellow
FROM 
      cte
```

Comment: Yeah ! same thing I have done and made a comment to Lamak post. But thanks. +1 to mention that.. I am sure others will also learn from this query

Comment: I've missed 2 lines previously. Corrected now  :)